# Copy semantic, Deep copy (C++)

Tags: c++, deep-copy

I have question of copy semantic in c++

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

class DeepCopy
{
private:
    int *_myInt;

public:
    DeepCopy(int val)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *_myInt = val;
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << std::endl;
    }
    ~DeepCopy()
    {
        free(_myInt);
        std::cout << "resource freed at address " << _myInt << std::endl;
    }
    DeepCopy(DeepCopy &source)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // line 1 
        *_myInt = *source._myInt;  // line 2
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << " with _myInt = " << *_myInt << std::endl;
    }
    DeepCopy &operator=(DeepCopy &source)
    {
        _myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        std::cout << "resource allocated at address " << _myInt << " with _myInt=" << *_myInt << std::endl;
        *_myInt = *source._myInt;
        return *this;
    }
    void printOwnAddress() { std::cout << "Own address on the stack is " << this << std::endl; }
    void printMemberAddress() { std::cout << "Managing memory block on the heap at " << _myInt << std::endl << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    DeepCopy source(42);
    source.printOwnAddress();
    source.printMemberAddress();
    DeepCopy dest1(source);
    dest1.printOwnAddress();
    dest1.printMemberAddress();

    source.printOwnAddress();
    source.printMemberAddress();
    return 0;
}
```

And the real result was in terminal:

```
resource allocated at address 0x2511c20
Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da00
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2511c20

resource allocated at address 0x2512050 with _myInt = 42
Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da10
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2512050

Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da00
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2511c20

resource freed at address 0x2512050
resource freed at address 0x2511c20
```

Let's see the DeepCopy(DeepCopy &source)

As my understanding,

1. line 1, It obtains new memory for _myInt,
2. line 2, Allocate the source's _myInt at the memory which is obtained line 1

So, I expected a result like

```
resource allocated at address 0x2511c20
Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da00
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2511c20

resource allocated at address 0x2512020 with _myInt = 42
Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da10
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2512020

Own address on the stack is 0x7ffdf539da00
Managing memory block on the heap at 0x2512050

resource freed at address 0x2512020
resource freed at address 0x2511c50
```

**Because the function DeepCopy(DeepCopy &source) change the source's member address, not destination's**

However, It is different from the above real result.

What I misunderstood?

Comment: Your assignment operator have three problems: First of all a memory leak, as you never free the existing memory; Secondly you dereference `_myInt` before you initialize that value; Lastly you don't check for self-assignment.

Comment: Assignment operator isn't called.

Comment: The actual output is correct, and it seems your expectations are wrong. Why do you think the objects should swap the pointers? The line in question `*_myInt = *source._myInt;` is copying the *value* from `*source._myInt` to `*_myInt`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I misunderstood it copies the address too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source._myInt` points to `0x2511c20`, before *and* after the copying. That doesn't change. `dest1._myInt` points to `0x2512050`, before and after the copying. Those two pointers do not change, and should not change.

The data stored at those memory locations is copied, but the pointers themselves are not copied.

Perhaps it's easier to understand if we draw it out for you:

First you create the `source` object:

```
DeepCopy source(42);
```

which creates something like this:

```
+---------------+     +----------------+
| source._myInt | --> | 42 @ 0x2511c20 |
+---------------+     +----------------+
```

Then you create the `dest1` object:

```
DeepCopy dest1(source);
```

If we take a step by step walk through the copy-constructor we first have

```
_myInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // line 1
```

This causes you to have

```
+--------------+     +----------------+
| dest1._myInt | --> | ?? @ 0x2512050 |
+--------------+     +----------------+
```

<sub>[The value is at this point *indeterminate*]</sub>

Then you have the copying of the *value*:

```
*_myInt = *source._myInt;  // line 2
```

And now you have

```
+--------------+     +----------------+
| dest1._myInt | --> | 42 @ 0x2512050 |
+--------------+     +----------------+
```

Finally we're back in the `main` function and you have:

```
+---------------+     +----------------+
| source._myInt | --> | 42 @ 0x2511c20 |
+---------------+     +----------------+

+--------------+     +----------------+
| dest1._myInt | --> | 42 @ 0x2512050 |
+--------------+     +----------------+
```

You have two different object, each with their own distinct `_myInt` variable, each pointing to different memory locations. The value in those locations happens to be the same, but the *pointers* to those values are different.